# Click on <a> text to checked input

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

How can I make sure that when I click on the text in `<a>` the checkbox is activated? Now when someone click on the text of the checkbox the drop down menu closes.
This is a simple snippet:

```
<div id="divChooseMacro" class="dropdown-menu" aria labelledby="choose-macro">
    <a class='dropdown-item' data-value='pippo' style='cursor: pointer;'> 
        <input type='checkbox' value='pippo'/>&nbsp; pippo 
    </a>
</div>
```

I try to set a `cursor: pointer` in the tag `<a>` but without success

Comment: You can't nest clickable elements like that, it's not valid HTML. Put the `input` outside of the `a` and solve both problems

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan If I put the `input` outside of the `a` it doesn't works! When I click on a element the dropdown closes immediately and the element doesn't checked

Comment: In which case you need a way to solve both problems. To help you with that we need to see all relevant code, including the JS which governs the menu you mention

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I don't write JS code, the behavior is due to the bootstrap standart library

Comment: Made an update to my answer, now dropdown keeps opened (i think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use label tag to relate it to the checkbox. Also, I've inserted some different semantic tags in your code: feel free to change it back.

About dropdown closing, you can stop click event to propagete at checkbox toggle its check, so bootstrap event listener for click would not be triggered

```
<ul id="divChooseMacro" class="dropdown-menu" aria labelledby="choose-macro">
  <li class='dropdown-item' data-value='pippo' style='cursor: pointer;'> 
    <label class='dropdown-item' onclick='event.stopPropagation();'> 
      <input type='checkbox' value='pippo'/>&nbsp; pippo 
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Since I'm not, just upvoted 3 of your past answers that was correct indeed. Hope you have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Just convert your `a` into a `label`, then when you click on the text, it checks the checkbox.

**Demo**

```html
<div id="divChooseMacro" class="dropdown-menu" aria labelledby="choose-macro">
    <label class='dropdown-item' data-value='pippo' style='cursor: pointer;'> 
        <input type='checkbox' value='pippo'/>&nbsp; pippo 
    </label>
</div>

<div id="divChooseMacro" class="dropdown-menu" aria labelledby="choose-macro">
    <label class='dropdown-item' data-value='pippo' style='cursor: pointer;'> 
        <input type='checkbox' value='222'/>&nbsp; 222 
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: This work partially, when you click on the element the dropdown closes